# javaClass.getResource("/foo") is null in IntelliJ but works on gradle CLI

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have some resources in "src/test/resources" and want to access them. It works fine on the command line with gradle - but when trying it in the IDE (intelliJ idea) it is null. Is this a bug from IntelliJ or am I missing something?

Comment: What [Run/Debug Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration.html) do you use to run application in IDE? When you run the application and access resources application resolves paths (if they are not absolute) relative the the application **working directory**. Check which working directory is set in Run/Debug Configuration

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am using a absolute path means accessing "/foo" which should map to "src/test/resources/foo"

Answer (score 0):

The problem was gone after deleting all iml files; the .idea folder and the .gradle folder